# How to install older Xcode version from the App Store

Tags: install, xcode, mac-appstore

I want to install Xcode 6 or 7 but I don't have a stable internet connection so installing the `.dmg` file with around 2-4GB file size will probably end badly. I was thinking of a way where I can install it safely where if I lose my internet or receive slow connection, I can automatically resume it normally without failing the download. This would be possible if I install it through the App Store but I can't seem to find how I can get specific versions.

Is there a way to do this or another method that would suit my situation?

Comment: Stable connection or not, using Safari, if a download has stopped without completing - you can resume the download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have previously purchased the xcode version you are interested in, you can download it again from the purchased tab in the app store

and

"There are older versions of Xcode available at the Apple Developer website, but as long as you just use the latest non-beta version of the SDK, you should be fine. E.g. just use Xcode 3.2.5 and iOS 4.2 SDK. The NDA only covers the pre-release versions"

from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839526/where-to-download-older-xcode-versions

Comment: It'll be my first time getting xcode. I know that I can get them from the apple developer website but the thing is I'm having trouble installing it through a browser since as I said, I have poor internet connection. Even 1GB Xcode 2 might fail halfway.

Comment: maybe just resuming the download can resolve you issue:
Firefox
1. Click the "Tools" or "Firefox" button at the top of the window.

2. Click "Downloads" to open the Downloads window.

3. Click the "Resume" button next to the paused item to continue the download. If you can't resume the download this way, click "Retry" to download the file from the beginning.

Chrome
1. Click on the Chrome menu button on the toolbar.

2. Click "Downloads." Alternatively, press "Ctrl-J" to open the Downloads page.

3. Click "Resume" to restart your download.